# copy a file from remote server and replace a string using ansible

Tags: ansible

I know that you can copy a file from a remote server to the local using ansible [with the fetch module.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html). You can even name the file with some variables related to the node you are fetching from. What I want to do, is to replace certain string on that file after copying it, ideally using inventory variables. Is this even possible? Is there any workaround that doesn't involves post-processing bash scripts?

Comment: I did something similar ... but it is quite long ago ... I don't remember exactly what I made, but I used if my memory is correct a `command: sed ......` on temporary file in a ram-drive before writting the file

Comment: may be `lineinfile` module? have you looked at it? `line` is what you assign. Also `regex` is supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have fetched the file, just use a delegation to localhost, via [`delegate_to`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation), of a [`replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html) task.

Given */tmp/somefile*

```
foo bar baz
This is an example string
Lorem Ipsum
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

And the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - fetch:
        src: /tmp/somefile
        dest: /tmp/fetched

    - replace:
        path: /tmp/fetched/{{ inventory_hostname }}/tmp/somefile
        regexp: "^This is an example string$"
        replace: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

It yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [fetch] *******************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

TASK [replace] *****************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1 -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And gives the file */tmp/fetched/host1/tmp/somefile* containing:

```
foo bar baz
host1
Lorem Ipsum
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I want. But why is the replace path different from the dest path on the fetch task?

Comment: Because I am not using the [`flat`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html#parameter-flat) parameter, so Ansible creates a folder in as the one I am passing as `dest`, creates a sub folder named as the host, and use then reproduce the `src` path to file.